# Trying to join two tables using LINQ, nothing is showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, linq

I've been experimenting with the various ways to interact with Databases using ASP.NET. For this purpose I created a database with four tables, linking them together using relationships based on their identity specification.

I'm trying to get the following query to work:

```
    from k in Klantens
    join b in Bestellingens on k.Klantnr equals b.B_klantnr
    join r in Bestelregels on b.Bestelnr equals r.Br_bestelnr
    join a in Artikelens on r.Br_artikelnr equals a.Artikelnr

    select new
    {
        k.Kl_anaam,
        k.Kl_vnaam,
        b.B_datum,
        b.B_status,
        a.Artikelnr,
        a.A_omsch,
        a.A_prijs,
        r.Br_aantal
    }
```

Doing this returns no records. 
I tried to figure out why it isn't returning anything by removing parts, but even when I do this, it returns no records:

```
    from k in Klantens
    join b in Bestellingens on k.Klantnr equals b.B_klantnr
    select new
    {
        k.Kl_anaam,
        b.B_status
    }
```

Trying to query from single tables works as expected, it's just the table joining I'm having issues with.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said your second code sample also gives no results. You code produces an `INNER JOIN`. Try the following sample code which will give you `LEFT JOIN`.

```
from k in Klantens
join b in Bestellingens on k.Klantnr equals b.B_klantnr into j
from b in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    k.Kl_anaam,
    b.B_status
}
```

See what it gives you and if there are actually values in `Bestellingens.B_klantnr` that match `Klantens.Klantnr`.

Comment: Using that query returns two records, which according to what I put in there is correct. However, it would appear that it can't read what's inside the b. fields, even if I swap them out to other fields in that table with different types. It's reading the values in k.Kl_anaam correctly though.

Comment: Is `Bestellingens.B_klantnr` field contains `NULL` values? Or the values don't match up with `Klantens.Klantnr`?

Comment: Wow, I'm such a tool. Turns out that when I was filling the data of the records in that table it never actually inserted them in for some reason. So yes, it did indeed contain `NULL` values. It works properly now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, it is possible there's something wrong with your equals operator? What type are k.Klantnr and b.B_klantnr etc?

Also you know that this doesn't return an actual enumerated result, right? It just returns an iterator that you then enumerate when you need to, if your database has already closed by that point then anything can happen (hopefully an exception, but not always). If this is a possibility then try calling ToList() on the result to force the query to execute immediately.

Comment: Every field that ends with 'nr' is an int. The ones without underscores are also set up as identifiers and key values.

After looking around some more I found out about a program called 'LINQPad4' which allows you to connect to a database and test my queries in there. 

Neither of the queries I mentioned in my post work, so I'm guessing that it might actually be something in the database itself?